# How to get a list of variable names from a c file in Python

Tags: python, parsing

I have a c file and would like to create a list of all variable names defined - using Python.

E.g. from the following c file

```
int mynum = 12;

// Timers
VAR_IN_SECTION(task_timers, .mem_layout)
timers_t timers[DSP_NUM_TASK_TIMERS];
```

I would like some Python magic to return

```
["mynum", "timers"]
```

How could this be done (in a way not specific to good c formatting), what would the Python magic be?

Note: This is for parsing a file that will only have variable declarations in it.

Comment: How is python supposed to know that `timers_t` is a variable declaration?  It seems to me that you'd need a complete c - parser, although, maybe not.  I suppose it's possible that just searching for `\w+\s+(\w+)` might be good enough ...

Comment: @mgilson Would you be able to post an answer to that effect?

Comment: Some variables would be easy to find... names following `int`, `char`, `float`... some would be a little more difficult such as things that were `typedef`'d... then there could be variables that aren't as clear.. things defined in header files or external libraries. How far are you looking to go?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the [GCC-XML](http://www.gccxml.org/) tool to convert the declarations of the C source file into XML. You could then use a Python XML parser (e.g. `lxml.etree`) to parse the results.

The GCC-XML output XML structure is fairly easy to parse. It will provide you with the variable declarations (tag: `<Variable>`) and type definitions (multiples tags, such as `<FundamentalType>`, `<Pointer>`, `<Struct>`, etc...). You need will to perform some processing to recursively derive the actual type (e.g. `Pointer` references a sub-type - the *pointed to* type), but it will provide you all you need if you're willing to spend some time on it.

If you want just the variable names, parse the XML for tag `Variable` and extract the attribute `name`.

Oddly enough, I am building exactly such a parser as part of a project. I am not (yet) allow to distribute but I am hoping it will be released open-sourced eventually.

Example:

```
typedef int* myintptr;

myintptr p;
```

Produces XML like this:

```
<Variable id="_3" name="p" type="_64" context="_1" location="f0:5" file="f0" line="5"/>
<Typedef id="_64" name="myintptr" type="_63" context="_1" location="f0:3" file="f0" line="3"/>
<PointerType id="_63" type="_156" size="64" align="64"/>
<FundamentalType id="_156" name="int" size="32" align="32"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

This works on the sample input file you gave, but I'm pretty sure that I'd need ALOT more tests before I would say that this works on c-syntax in general:

```
>>> s = """int mynum = 12;
... 
... // Timers
... VAR_IN_SECTION(task_timers, .mem_layout)
... timers_t timers[DSP_NUM_TASK_TIMERS];"""
>>>
>>> import re
>>> re.findall(r'\w+[ \t]+(\w+)',s)
['mynum', 'timers']
```

The answer posted above won't pick up pointers:

```
int *p;
```

To pick those up, maybe adjusting the regex a little:

```
>>> re.findall(r'\w+[ \t]+(?:\*\s*)?(\w+)',s)
['mynum', 'timers', 'p']
```

with C, you can't look for various types (`int`,`float`,`double`,`char` ...) because things can always be typedef'd and you also have `struct` (and `union`?) which work like that too...
Not to mention that any any point, you can `#include "anyfile.c"` -- Which would be a pretty nasty thing to do as a programmer, but it's possible.  I think with `c99` you can also declare variables anywhere you want (e.g. in a macro).  Do you want to pick those up too?  In other words, to do this correctly, you need a full c-parser to do the heavy lifting for you

Comment: of course a string literal with spaces in it, a `#define` or a `typedef` will kill it.

Comment: This is actually really good, only problem is it picks up comments too. e.g. `// Test comment` ends up with `comment` in the variable array using the above.

Comment: @Mike -- I suppose that we could strip comments, `typedef`, string literals and `#define` statements while we're at it ...

Comment: Truth is gccxml would be the most reliable solution but this is just for personal code I know will be formatted in the way described above and the c file is just for variable declarations. I would much prefer the one line regex solution to firing up a `subprocess`

Comment: I have +1 this answer because I used it, however for others, I have marked gccxml as the answer because of it's reliability. Thank you.